# How To Check Google Play Game Services Leaderboard - Best Score of All Player?

Tags: android, google-play-services

How I can see the highest score and the player/profile name that playing my game? I just see my score and my friends score.

Thanks

Adi

Comment: Is your app and game services backend published or still in testing mode?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot It's still in testing mode.